# Is it possible to get yarn application id using application name via yarn cli

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running my spark application on yarn. Is it possible to get application id for my application, using application name through yarn cli?

Comment: Try something like `yarn application -list | grep APPNAME | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use yarn application commands. Something like :

```
yarn application -list | grep your_app_name
```

For additional info, you can refer https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#application